# Can I use the "baseHref" option for assets only, without affecting routes or Http calls

Tags: angular

I have this problem where I've set the `baseHref` option in angular.json to "assets/app/dist". This is working well for my assets and I'm no longer getting 404s on them. The undesired consequence, though, is that all my routes now start with "assets/app/dist". So a route that used to look like "http://localhost:9000/#/home" now looks like "http://localhost:9000/assets/app/dist/#/home".

Is there a way that I can have the baseHref apply only to my assets and not my routes? I should mention that I'm using the `useHash` option for my app routes

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    useHash: true,
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
});
```

Comment: You has no understand the "baseHref". Your app **are** yet in assets/app/dist: the .html, the .js and a copy of your assets. So when you want to "get" an img.jpg in assets the route in .html should be `src="/assets/myimagen.jpg"` (but the baseHref is "/", really you use baseHref when you has differents languages, e.g. your url is www.mydominio.com in your idiom and www.mydominio/es-ES in Spanish (the baseHref in this last should be "/es-ES") or diferent dominios, you want your url in mydominio/booking.